# Save webpage as opera web document

Tags: c, opera

Is there a way using c to save a retrieved webpage as an opera web document(.mht)? I can retrieve the page and save as html, but is there a way to convert it into this format?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Did you look into the [Chilkat MHT library](http://www.chilkatsoft.com/mht-library.asp)?